# select array value of an object in php

Tags: php, arrays, object

I'm just a beginner and would like to select a value of an array inside an object. I'm quite lost and don't know how to do.

ie : how to get de value of "thailande" inside this object ?

```
Forminator_Form_Entry_Model Object
(
    [entry_id] => 42
    [entry_type] => custom-forms
    [form_id] => 24342
    [is_spam] => 0
    [date_created_sql] => 2020-07-02 11:42:21
    [date_created] => 2 Juil 2020
    [time_created] => 2 Juil 2020 @ 11:42  
    [meta_data] => Array
        (
            [select-1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 87
                    [value] => thailande
                )

            [radio-1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 88
                    [value] => 1
                )

            [number-1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 89
                    [value] => 10
                )

            [_forminator_user_ip] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 90
                    [value] => 84.101.156.169
                )

        )

    [table_name:protected] => politis_5_frmt_form_entry
    [table_meta_name:protected] => politis_5_frmt_form_entry_meta
)
```

thx a lot for your help.

Comment: Once i see "protected" *anywhere* i know you should be using their api. Why are you not using their "getters"?

Comment: _“I'm just a beginner”_ appears to be everyone’s excuse these days for dragging stuff here, that they should be learning from a couple of beginner tutorials …

Comment: $obj->meta_data["select-1"]["value"]

So simple. thx for your help !!!! I'm so ashamed ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly straightforward - you just go down the hierarchy one step at a time referencing the index you need.

So, assuming `$obj` in this example is an instance of `Forminator_Form_Entry_Model` then you would write

```
$obj->meta_data["select-1"]["value"]
```

which will point to the data you're looking for.

N.B. The `->index` syntax is used to get properties of an object. the `["index"]` syntax is used to get properties of an array.

Answer (score -1):

> You can try Callback Functions

```
function array_search_id($val_for_search, $array_data, $search_in_path='root') { 
  
        if(is_array($array_data) && count($array_data) > 0) { // if value has child
              
            foreach($array_data as $key => $value) { 
      
                $paths_list = $search_in_path; 
                  
                // Adding current key to search path 
                array_push($paths_list, $key); 
       
                if(is_array($value) && count($value) > 0) { // if value has child

                    $res = array_search_id($val_for_search, $value, $paths_list);//callback function 
      
                    if ($res != null)  
                        return $res; 
                     
                } 
                  else if($value == $val_for_search){
                    
                    //if you wants path + result
                    return end($paths_list);  
                    
                    /*
                    //if you wants path
                    return join(" --> ", $paths_list);  
                    */
                }  //if value find in array return val 
                  
                 
            } 
        }  
        return null; 
    } 
array_search_id('thailande', $your_array);
```